# Arduino C++ class with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, class, arduino

I'm building a class that should have an array in it.  I'm currently trying to pass an array, but the array can be any sized. When I try to do that, it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?. I'm currently having some trouble with it, but here's my code:

Relay.cpp

```
Relay::Relay(short pins[])
{
    _relay = pins;
    _binding = new short[length()];
    for(short i=0; i<length(); i++)
        _binding[i]=0;
}

short Relay::length()
{
    return sizeof(_relay)/sizeof(short);
}
```

Relay.h

```
class Relay
{
    public:
        Relay(short pins[]);
        short length();
    private:
        short *_relay;
        short *_binding;
};
```

when I create the instance:

```
Relay reles((short[]){11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 73, 4, A0, A1, A2, A3, A4});
```

EDIT: After the suggestion of Resident biscuit I ended up with the cpp file like this but it gives me undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned int) error. Besides, When I try to access _pins and show the contents use in _pins[i] it does not show me what I passed on instance. For example, if I show what is on _pins[0] it should return 11, but it doesn't.

Comment: Where does length() come from?

Comment: I forgot to post that function, now updated.

Comment: You can't pass an array to a function in C++.  It degrades to a pointer, so your `length()` function is wrong (which should be obvious, considering you declare `_relay` (appropriately) as a pointer.

Comment: What if I declare them as _relay[]? I'm not really used to code c++, as I normally program Java or C#.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate some memory if you're going to use this approach.

`_bindings = new short[size];`

Don't forget to free this memory whenever you are done with it.

`delete[] _bindings;`

Comment: I updated my code with the instance (I don't know if I can do that either). I'm going to try that :D

Comment: I tried to do that but it gives me this error: undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned int)

Comment: That's not good RAII, you should "never" use delete (unless you're writing a container).

Comment: The Arduino language doesn't support the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic array in C++ is found under the name vector. You call would become:

```
class Relay
{
    public:
        Relay(const std::vector<short> &pins) 
           : _binding(pins.size()), _relay(pins) {}
    private:
        std::vector<short> _relay;
        std::vector<short> _binding;
};


int main() {
  // C++ 11
  //  Relay r({1, 2, 3, 4});

  // C++03
  short arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::vector<short> v(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
  Relay r(v);
}
```

There are multiple issues in your code, for instance:

```
short *_relay;
```

is a pointer, sizeof(_relay) is the size of the pointer, nothing to do with the size of the memory allocation it points to. So  sizeof(_relay)/sizeof(short); is equivalent to  sizeof(short *)/sizeof(short); which does not really make any sense.

When you do:

```
_relay = _pins;
```

you are copying a pointer, now _relay points to the same place _pins point. However this memory where they points to was "volatile": it is a temporary you allocated at the call site. It will be de-allocated as soon as the call return. Your pointer is now pointing to an area you should not access anymore.

Comment: I'd recommend changing the constructor line to:
` : _relay(pins), _binding(pins.length() {}` 
because they are initialized in the order of declaration and it's potentially confusing to list them the other way in the initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I understood my problem, but now I have another question.  How should I instance an object of Relay class? thanks!

Comment: It depends, do you use a c++11 compiler?

Comment: As I said this is a class to use with Arduino. I'm currently using notepad++ or Sublime Text to code them, but the compiler is from arduino

Comment: Ok I updated with how I would do it in C++03, and I added in a comment the C++11 version, so much nicer :)
Note that there is *nothing* Arduino specific here. It is pure standard C++.

Comment: The Arduino does not use standard C++ specifically the STL is not available on Arduino. See the [avr-libc FAQ](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus)

Comment: That's quite unfortunate :(

Answer (score 0):

It's generally questionable class design to have a C++ class contain a pointer to "outside data."  Often a better way to do it is to have your C++ use a copy of the external data, so it's clear that the memory is de-allocated when the class instance is destroyed.

Also as someone else mentioned, some of these things are much easier to do with C++11.  If you're using `g++` or `clang++` as your compiler, you may already have support for C++11, which makes a lot of things very nice and easy, especially for embedded system work.

In this particular case, here's a complete and compilable program (I used `g++` and compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 -o relay relay.cpp` with the following as the contents of `relay.cpp`.  I've combined everything into a single file for simplicity of illustration, but in real life, you should keep the separation of `.cpp` and `.h` files that you already had.

#include 
   #include

```
class Relay
{
    public:
        Relay(std::vector<short> pins)
            : _relay(pins), _binding(pins.size()) {}
        // these are just diagnostics for testing the class
        std::ostream& printPins(std::ostream &out) {
                for (auto i : _relay) 
                      out << i << ' '; 
                   out << std::endl; 
        }
        std::ostream& printBindings(std::ostream &out) { 
                for (auto i : _binding) 
                    out << i << ' '; 
                out << std::endl; 
        }
    private:
        std::vector<short> _relay;
        std::vector<short > _binding;
};

enum {A0=80, A1, A2, A3, A4};

int main()
{
    Relay reles{std::vector<short>{11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 73, 
                                 4, A0, A1, A2, A3, A4}};
    reles.printPins(std::cout);
    reles.printBindings(std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

The `enum` for the `A0` through `A4` lines are just for completeness in this example, but they might be `#define` or `const int` declarations.  It doesn't matter.

The two `print...()` functions are only for illustration to demonstrate that it's actually doing what's expected.  In this case, the output is:

```
11 10 9 8 7 3 2 73 4 80 81 82 83 84 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) is part of the standard library and could be used even if you're not using C++11.  If you are, then you can take advantage of such interesting things as *move* semantics and *constexpr* and other goodies that are of particular use in embedded systems.  One such nice feature is called a **list initialization** and is used within `main` in this sample program.  In this line:

```
    Relay reles{std::vector<short>{11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 73, 4, A0, A1, A2, A3, A4}};
```

A temporary `std::vector<short>` is created and then used to initialize the `reles` class instantiation.  A clever compiler can, under some circumstances, optimize away the creation of such temporaries.  As always, looking at the actual assembly language output is useful for evaluating particular techniques and particular compilers.

Another thing that I find very useful is the `for (auto i : _relay)` style of `for` loop. This tells the compiler to automatically infer the type for `i` by treating `relay` as a collection of something.  Very concise and very handy.

If you're not yet familiar with the C++ language (or just the relatively new parts), I'd recommend getting a book such as Stroustrup's **The C++ Programming Language, fourth ed.**.

**Edit**:
In the unfortunate case that you have a very limited C++ compiler, as seems to be the [the situation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_cplusplus) with the Arduino, you'll need to do things differently.  Specifically, because you don't have an `operator new` or `operator delete` you'll have to either pre-allocate some maximum size for your arrays, or simply rely on those being passed in as part of the initialization.  Here's one way to do that:

```
#include <cassert>

class Relay
{
    public:
        Relay(int numpins, short *pins, short *bindings)
            : _numpins(numpins), _relay(pins), _binding(bindings) {}
    short pin(int i) 
    {
    if ((i < 0) || (i >= _numpins))
        return -1;
    return _relay[i];
    }
    short binding(int i)
    {
    if ((i < 0) || (i >= _numpins))
        return -1;
    return _binding[i];
    }
    private:
        int _numpins;
        short *_relay;
        short *_binding;
};

enum {A0=80, A1, A2, A3, A4};

int main()
{
    const int numpins = 14;
    short pins[numpins] = {11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 73, 
                           4, A0, A1, A2, A3, A4};
    short bindings[numpins] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
                           8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    Relay reles(numpins, pins, bindings);
    assert(reles.pin(0) == 11);
    assert(reles.binding(4) == 5);

    return 0;
}
```